# Subtract values from different locations on two sheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

The ideal solution for this would be in VBA and not a formula because I need the first sheet to reset itself each time thus a formula would get overwritten.

I have two sheets:

```
Sheet1 (Subtract Inventory)

Item#   Sold
1022    23
1024    56
1025    52

Sheet2 (Count)

Item#   Count
1020    1027
1021    99
1022    76
1023    128
1024    57
1025    1023
1026    987
```

What I would like to do is have VBA code that will update `Sheet2` by subtracting the "Sold" on `Sheet1` from the "Count" on `Sheet2`.  The result would look something like this:

```
Sheet2 (Count)

Item#   Count
1020    1027
1021    99
1022    53
1023    128
1024    1
1025    971
1026    987
```

I have been able to figure out several codes but I can never get them to fit.  And `Sheet1` will have users paste info from a website so it will have to base the search on the Item number and not column A.

I think the best thing to do is a restart to make sure that I am not messing up by starting off in the wrong direction. Does anyone have any idea where to begin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way using **Vlookup**

Hope this is what you are trying?

**TRIED AND TESTED**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim ws1LastRow As Long, ws2LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim SearchRange As Range

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws1LastRow = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set SearchRange = ws1.Range("A1:B" & ws1LastRow)

    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    With ws2
        ws2LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To ws2LastRow
            On Error Resume Next
            If Not IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("A" & i).Value, SearchRange, 2, False)) Then
                .Range("B" & i).Value = .Range("B" & i).Value - _
                Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("A" & i).Value, SearchRange, 2, False)
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next i
    End With

    '~~> Clear Sheet1 for next input
    ws1.Cells.ClearContents

    '~~> Clean Up
    Set SearchRange = Nothing
    Set ws1 = Nothing
    Set ws2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

**FOLLOWUP**

The cleaning that you are doing at the moment is not correct. If I manually do the cleaning the sheet should look like this?

[image]

Also if you notice that then numbers are stored as text or have blank spaces. Vlookup will fail in these scenarios.

[image]

In such a case, I recommend the following

**1)** You need to have a macro in places which cleans your data more effectively for input

**2)** Either you move the "SKU" before the "QTY" and then use Vlookup **OR** use an alternate method.

**3)** If you are interested in an alternate method then see (**Section 4**) in this link

http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

Comment: This does everything I need but it doesn't interact with sheet two for some reason.  What year is your excel?  Mine is 2003... do you think that messes it up?

Comment: I have all versions of Excel starting from 2003. The problem is not because of the version. What do you mean when you say "it doesn't interact with sheet two"

Comment: First I want to say, I suck at tact when I am typing.  I assure you that I am very thankful for your help.  Second... I put your code in as you typed it and it does everything that is needed except it didn't update the cells on sheet two for me.  They all remained the same no matter how many times I tried. Please advise.  I haven't taken a VBA class for awhile and I might have forgotten some of the basics.  What info would you request from me?

Comment: For a speedy solution can you upload a sample of your workbook in wikisend.com and then share the link here?

Comment: ok, I have never worked with that cite before so it will take me a few minutes

Comment: You can upload it to any file hosting site. You can even use skydrive if you have an hotmail account

Comment: I checked the file. Where have you implemented the code that I gave above?

Comment: Try this one, I just added notes.  If you look at the notes you will see where the code needs to go.

Comment: You still didn't get my point. The code that I gave above, You haven't used in the sheet. I would like to know why?

Comment: I did, then it didn't work so I took it out of the place that I put in my notes so that I could try the code that the next guy suggested.  I only deleted it because someone else made a suggestion and I thought I should try it.  Your code has been the closest to giving me the desired results.  I tried to work with it for awhile and I couldn't get it to work.  I will upload it again.

Comment: Please do not just copy and paste the code. Show me the changes that you made. :) I will simply amend the code to make it work. :)

Comment: Really, thank you for your help.  The information that you are giving me will give me the understanding that I need to work on coding the other pages myself.This really helps me.

Comment: Why are you using this `Set ws1 = Sheets("Subtract Invintory")` when there is nothing in that sheet?

Comment: thats the sheet that we will paste the information into.  A webcite will give my "business" a list of all the orders for that day and we will just copy and paste it onto that page.  then the other lines of code that I made will make it into something usable.  My teacher is very detailed in his homework assignments.  I think he might be using an actual business as our example.

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at it?

Comment: Honestly no. The reason is The sheet where you are pasting data is empty and I am not sure on how and where will you be pasting the data. Can you show me a file which has data already pasted so that I can test my code before posting?

Comment: This has a sample of 6 orders that have simular items in it.

Comment: There are lot of issues here. let me explain it with snapshots. Updating the post shortly

Comment: Ok, I did a edit to my macro and now it edits formats it and arranges it like you suggested, but it still wont subtract the values from the next sheet.

Comment: https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=6c08299e32f15440&resid=6C08299E32F15440!144&parid=6C08299E32F15440!126&authkey=!AJU2chz8inMGIvA

Comment: I am not sure if you are making changes to the files that I am uploading or not but I cant view them after I add them because I have excel 2003 and not 2010

Comment: I just tried the code and it gave me an error. And the reason is because the sheet is still not formatted properly ;) if you just run your code (and not mine) then you will notice that there are 0's from Row 26 to Row 65536. because of this `ws1LastRow = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` line fails. If you delete all rows from 26 till 65536 then my code will work. I just tested it :) So you need to clean up your base sheet before you run the code.

Comment: Finally, I have been working on this for weeks.  I got it finished.  This code was exactally what I needed.  I am so glad I have another week to finish it before I turn it in.

Comment: Hey, can you help me with an adaptation of this code?  If I have two orders of the same product then it only takes out the first count.  I cant get it to process the second one.

Comment: https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=6c08299e32f15440&resid=6C08299E32F15440!145&parid=6C08299E32F15440!126&authkey=!AMF4qJ6rhO5P1W4

Answer (score 0):

*Formula method:*

1. On sheet2 in C2 put this formula

   **=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2, Sheet1!A:A, 0)), B2 - VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet1!A:B, 2, 0), B2)**
2. Copy that formula down the data set
3. Copy the set of new data in C2:C???
4. Click on B2 and select **Edit > Paste Special > Values**
5. Clear column C...you're done

*Macro method (same approach)*

```
Sub UpdateSheet2()
Dim LR As Long

With Sheets("Sheet2")
    LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    With .Range("C2:C" & LR)
        .Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2, Sheet1!A:A, 0)), B2 - VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet1!A:B, 2, 0), B2)"
        .Offset(, -1).Value = .Value
        .Value = ""
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but It wasn't working for me... I made an edit and changed the name to what it is in my program.  I am having a problem now with a box that is popping up at the end.  I think that it is trying to save my file but it doesn't change the count on my second sheet "Count".  Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: What box?  What did you change? I can't help with what I can't see.

Comment: You should use the FORMULA version first. Put that in manually and edit until it works to show the first value.  Then Post that formula and I can help adjust the MACRO version above to use that corrected formula.

Comment: Sorry Jerry, I changed the name of the sheet because I was getting confused with the wording.  Please bear with me, I am new to this.

Comment: Jerry,  I tried to do the Formula that you suggested and it said that it would not allow a "circular reference".  Please advise. I have Excel 2003.

Comment: You can't put a formula in A1 that refers to A1 IN the formula.  What is the formula you're trying to put in?

Comment: =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2, Sheet1!A:A, 0)), B2 - VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet1!A:B, 2, 0), B2)

Comment: That's fine if that formula is going on Sheet2.  What cell/sheet were you putting that in?

Comment: Do you want me to send you a copy of the file?

Comment: Sure, if you'd like.  My site is in my profile, send to me through there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be resolved through a simple code as under:

```
For sht2 = 2 To 8 ' Sheet2 rows
For sht1 = 2 To 4 ' Sheet1 rows
If Cells(sht2, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(sht1, 1).Value Then
Cells(sht2, 2).Value = Cells(sht2, 2).Value - Sheet1.Cells(sht1, 2).Value
End If
Next
Next
```

The 2 to 8 rows in Sheet2 and 2 to 4 rows in Sheet1 are based on the example quoted. However the number of rows in each sheet ie Sales Data Sheet and the Stock data sheet can be captured by use of Cells.End method as in:

```
For sht2 = 2 to sheet2.Cells(2,2).End(XlDown).Row +1 ' for Sheet2 rows
For sht1 = 2 to Sheet1.Cells(2,2).End(XlDown).Row +1 ' for Sheet1 rows
```

The loop above iterates through all the cells having data and deducts the stock through the If statement

Comment: Two things with this one. First off this is an example so my real sheets are longer then 4 and 8 rows. Sadly the 4 row sheet will have to change each time. Second, Do I put "sht2 = sheets("Count")" after my Sub line?